# How can I change delegate methods with blocks?

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

I want to transform a regular delegate pattern into an asynchronous block like UIView animations does. I want to do what Apple did with UIView animations, I want to substitute something like this

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIview setAnimationDuration:0.25f];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(myStopSelector)];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

// Animation stuff

[UIView commitAnimations];

// In another part of my class

- (void)myStopSelector {

    // Completion stuff
}
```

with something like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{

    // Animation stuff

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    // Completion stuff
}]
```

In my case, I want this behaviour while waiting for an asynchronous operation; now I'm adding an observer that listens for a certain protocol to completion of the operation, with the results. I want to avoid using delegate pattern to use an asynchonorus completion handler block like TWRequest does

```
[myTWRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

}];
```

How can I do that?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your class will provide one or methods that take blocks as parameters. You need to decide if these blocks should run on the main queue, a concurrent background queue, or a serial background queue. In the latter cases your class must create and manage these queues.

It the blocks are to be run when after some event, they you store the blocks in some container, and when that event queue them on a queue. Or you can suspend the queue, add the blocks, and resume the queue when the event happens.

What I suggest you do is create a demo project, and play around with these ideas before you go and try to add code to your existing project. GCD and blocks gives you a rich set of tools, and you could create many solutions that would accomplish your goals.

EDIT:

Resources:
Apple Docs:
- 'Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference' - gives you a great idea of the depth and breadth of the technology

- 'Concurrency and Application Design' - more of the same
- 'Blocks Programming Topics'

Mike Ash on his [Friday Q&A](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/) series has several great articles on using blocks and queues:

Comment: Thank you David. Do you know some resources or tutorials to begin with those concepts?